# How to pass multiple values in XML attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am a little bit new to SOAP request and response. I am working on a project assigned to me where our partner has provided us their WSDL file. In a request, they have mentioned an attribute which accepts multiple values.

For the values to be passed they have provided us '*.xsd' file. Now I don't have any idea how can I pass the request and also how I can pass multiple values in the attribute using the provided *.xsd file in C#.Net. How can I tackle this?

Below is an example of soap request generated through SoapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cre="http://creation.soapws.progressoft.com/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <cre:paymentOperation>?</cre:paymentOperation>
      <cre:requestTimeStamp>?</cre:requestTimeStamp>
      <cre:securityToken>?</cre:securityToken>
      <cre:username>?</cre:username>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cre:createPayment>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <remitterBankBIC>?</remitterBankBIC>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <requestMsg>?</requestMsg>
      </cre:createPayment>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Note: In the above sample the attribute in which I have to pass multiple values.

```
<requestMsg>?</requestMsg>
```

Below is the xsd sample:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://opay.progressoft.com/PaymentCreationSchema" 
xmlns:tns="http://opay.progressoft.com/PaymentCreationSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<element name="file" type="tns:paymentItem"/>
 <complexType name="PaymentRequest">
    <sequence>
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs='1' name="recordType" type="tns:BodyRecordType"/> 
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs='1' name="transactionReference" type="tns:Max20Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs='1' name="transactionDate" type="date"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="senderCurrency" type="tns:CurrencyCode"/>
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs='1' name="beneficiaryCurrency" type="tns:CurrencyCode"/>
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs='1' name="transferAmount" type="tns:PaymentAmount"/>
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs='1' name="remitterFirstName" type="tns:Max30Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs='1' name="remitterMiddleName" type="tns:Max30Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="remitterLastName1" type="tns:Max30Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="remitterLastName2" type="tns:Max40Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="remitterNationality" type="tns:Max30Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="remitterMobileNo" type="tns:Mobile"/>
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs='1' name="remitterAddress1" type="tns:Max100Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="remitterAddress2" type="tns:Max100Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="remitterAddress3" type="tns:Max100Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="payerOtherInfo1" type="tns:Max50Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="payerOtherInfo2" type="tns:Max50Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs='1' name="beneficiaryFirstName" type="tns:Max30Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs='1' name="beneficiaryMiddleName" type="tns:Max30Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="beneficiaryLastName1" type="tns:Max30Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="beneficiaryLastName2" type="tns:Max30Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="beneficiaryNationality" type="tns:Max40Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="beneficiaryMobile" type="tns:Mobile"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="beneficiaryEmailID" type="tns:Max60Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="beneficiaryAddress1" type="tns:Max100Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="beneficiaryAddress2" type="tns:Max100Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="beneficiaryAddress3" type="tns:Max100Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="beneficiaryBankBICCode" type="tns:Max35Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="beneficiaryIBAN" type="tns:Max35Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="beneficiaryBranchName" type="tns:Max35Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="beneficiaryID" type="tns:Max50Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="benOtherInfo1" type="tns:Max50Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="benOtherInfo2" type="tns:Max50Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs='1' name="transferPurpose" type="tns:Max105Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs='1' name="chargeType" type="tns:ChargeType"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="optionalField1" type="tns:Max50Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="optionalField2" type="tns:Max50Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="optionalField3" type="tns:Max50Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="optionalField4" type="tns:Max50Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="optionalField5" type="tns:Max50Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="optionalField6" type="tns:Max50Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="optionalField7" type="tns:Max50Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="optionalField8" type="tns:Max50Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="optionalField9" type="tns:Max50Text"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='1' name="optionalField10" type="tns:Max50Text"/>
        </sequence>
     </complexType>

 <complexType name="paymentItem">
    <sequence>
      <element type="tns:PaymentRequest" name="payment"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

    <complexType name="PaymentResponse">
        <sequence>
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs='1' name="recordType" type="tns:BodyRecordType"/> 
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="transactionReference" type="tns:Max20Text" />
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="resolution" type="tns:Max10Text" /> <!--  add enum for resolution -->
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="rejectionReasonCode" type="tns:Max03Text" />
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="rejectionReasonDescription" type="tns:Max70Text" />
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="custAcctName" type="tns:Max80Text" />
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="corrBankCharge" type="tns:PaymentAmount" />
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="corrSwiftCharge" type="tns:PaymentAmount" />
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="cbjCharge" type="tns:PaymentAmount" />
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="netAmt" type="tns:PaymentAmount" />
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="netAmtCrncy" type="tns:CurrencyCode" />
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="rateCode" type="tns:Max08Text" />
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="rate" type="tns:Rate" />
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="originalAmtJOD" type="tns:PaymentAmount" />
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="tranId" type="tns:Max09Text" />
            <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="tranDate" type="date" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <simpleType name="Mobile">
        <restriction base="string">
            <pattern value="[00|+][0-9]{28}"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="PaymentAmount">
        <restriction base="decimal">
            <minInclusive value="0.00"/>
            <fractionDigits value="3"/>
            <totalDigits value="17"/>
            <maxInclusive value="99999999999999.99"/>
            <pattern value="[0-9]{0,14}([\.]([0-9]{0,3})){0,1}"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>

    <simpleType name="Rate">
        <restriction base="decimal">
            <minInclusive value="0.00"/>
            <fractionDigits value="7"/>
            <totalDigits value="10"/>
            <maxInclusive value="999.9999999"/>
            <pattern value="[0-9]{0,3}([\.]([0-9]{0,7})){0,1}"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>

    <simpleType name="ChargeType">
        <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="BEN"/>
            <enumeration value="OUR"/>
            <enumeration value="SHA"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>    
    <simpleType name="BodyRecordType">
        <restriction base="string">
            <pattern value="[D]{1,1}"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="CurrencyCode">
        <restriction base="string">
            <pattern value="[A-Z]{3,3}"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="Max03Text">
        <restriction base="string">
            <minLength value="0"/>
            <maxLength value="3"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>    
    <simpleType name="Max08Text">
        <restriction base="string">
            <minLength value="0"/>
            <maxLength value="8"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>    
    <simpleType name="Max09Text">
        <restriction base="string">
            <minLength value="0"/>
            <maxLength value="9"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>     
    <simpleType name="Max10Text">
        <restriction base="string">
            <minLength value="0"/>
            <maxLength value="10"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="Max105Text">
        <restriction base="string">
            <minLength value="0"/>
            <maxLength value="105"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="Max100Text">
        <restriction base="string">
            <minLength value="0"/>
            <maxLength value="100"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>    
    <simpleType name="Max20Text">
        <restriction base="string">
            <minLength value="0"/>
            <maxLength value="20"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="Max35Text">
        <restriction base="string">
            <minLength value="0"/>
            <maxLength value="35"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="Max40Text">
        <restriction base="string">
            <minLength value="0"/>
            <maxLength value="40"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="Max30Text">
        <restriction base="string">
            <minLength value="0"/>
            <maxLength value="30"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="Max50Text">
        <restriction base="string">
            <minLength value="0"/>
            <maxLength value="50"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="Max70Text">
        <restriction base="string">
            <minLength value="0"/>
            <maxLength value="70"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="Max60Text">
        <restriction base="string">
            <minLength value="0"/>
            <maxLength value="70"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="Max80Text">
        <restriction base="string">
            <minLength value="0"/>
            <maxLength value="80"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>       


</schema>
```

Comment: Generally if you can pass multiple values Soap UI will generate like `<requestMsg><!-Optional:--><string>?</string</requestMsg>`. Since it has not generated it like this, I doubt it can take multiple values

Comment: n.b. that isn't an attribute. That is called an *element*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change code base on the schema you provided.  Used the xsd tool to generate classes.  Had to get the soap schema from the web and make minor changes to the soap classes to add your specific items.  The schema is not giving same results as your sample xml.  I think the schema is correct and your sample is wrong :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string operation = "Purchase";
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string token = "12345";
            string name = "John Smith";
            string bank = "BOA";
            string message = "Paid in Full";

            XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            namespaces.Add("cre", "http://creation.soapws.progressoft.com/");

            Envelope envelope = new Envelope()
            {
                Header = new EnvelopeHeader[] {
                    new EnvelopeHeader() { paymentOperation = operation, requestTimeStamp = now, securityToken = token, username = name}
                },
                Body = new EnvelopeBody[] {
                    new EnvelopeBody() {
                        item = new paymentItem() {
                            payment = new PaymentRequest[] {
                                new PaymentRequest() {
                                     beneficiaryBranchName = bank,
                                     transactionDate = now,
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope), "soapenv:http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();

            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates;
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;


            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, envelope, namespaces);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            //writer.Dispose();

        }
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // <auto-generated>
    //     This code was generated by a tool.
    //     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.6421
    //
    //     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
    //     the code is regenerated.
    // </auto-generated>
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //using System.Xml.Serialization;

    // 
    // This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=2.0.50727.3038.
    // 


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://opay.progressoft.com/PaymentCreationSchema")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("file", Namespace="http://opay.progressoft.com/PaymentCreationSchema", IsNullable=false)]
    public partial class paymentItem {

        private PaymentRequest[] paymentField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("payment")]
        public PaymentRequest[] payment {
            get {
                return this.paymentField;
            }
            set {
                this.paymentField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://opay.progressoft.com/PaymentCreationSchema")]
    public partial class PaymentRequest {

        private string recordTypeField;

        private string transactionReferenceField;

        private System.DateTime transactionDateField;

        private string senderCurrencyField;

        private string beneficiaryCurrencyField;

        private decimal transferAmountField;

        private string remitterFirstNameField;

        private string remitterMiddleNameField;

        private string remitterLastName1Field;

        private string remitterLastName2Field;

        private string remitterNationalityField;

        private string remitterMobileNoField;

        private string remitterAddress1Field;

        private string remitterAddress2Field;

        private string remitterAddress3Field;

        private string payerOtherInfo1Field;

        private string payerOtherInfo2Field;

        private string beneficiaryFirstNameField;

        private string beneficiaryMiddleNameField;

        private string beneficiaryLastName1Field;

        private string beneficiaryLastName2Field;

        private string beneficiaryNationalityField;

        private string beneficiaryMobileField;

        private string beneficiaryEmailIDField;

        private string beneficiaryAddress1Field;

        private string beneficiaryAddress2Field;

        private string beneficiaryAddress3Field;

        private string beneficiaryBankBICCodeField;

        private string beneficiaryIBANField;

        private string beneficiaryBranchNameField;

        private string beneficiaryIDField;

        private string benOtherInfo1Field;

        private string benOtherInfo2Field;

        private string transferPurposeField;

        private string chargeTypeField;

        private string optionalField1Field;

        private string optionalField2Field;

        private string optionalField3Field;

        private string optionalField4Field;

        private string optionalField5Field;

        private string optionalField6Field;

        private string optionalField7Field;

        private string optionalField8Field;

        private string optionalField9Field;

        private string optionalField10Field;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string recordType {
            get {
                return this.recordTypeField;
            }
            set {
                this.recordTypeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string transactionReference {
            get {
                return this.transactionReferenceField;
            }
            set {
                this.transactionReferenceField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="date")]
        public System.DateTime transactionDate {
            get {
                return this.transactionDateField;
            }
            set {
                this.transactionDateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string senderCurrency {
            get {
                return this.senderCurrencyField;
            }
            set {
                this.senderCurrencyField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string beneficiaryCurrency {
            get {
                return this.beneficiaryCurrencyField;
            }
            set {
                this.beneficiaryCurrencyField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public decimal transferAmount {
            get {
                return this.transferAmountField;
            }
            set {
                this.transferAmountField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string remitterFirstName {
            get {
                return this.remitterFirstNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.remitterFirstNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string remitterMiddleName {
            get {
                return this.remitterMiddleNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.remitterMiddleNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string remitterLastName1 {
            get {
                return this.remitterLastName1Field;
            }
            set {
                this.remitterLastName1Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string remitterLastName2 {
            get {
                return this.remitterLastName2Field;
            }
            set {
                this.remitterLastName2Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string remitterNationality {
            get {
                return this.remitterNationalityField;
            }
            set {
                this.remitterNationalityField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string remitterMobileNo {
            get {
                return this.remitterMobileNoField;
            }
            set {
                this.remitterMobileNoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string remitterAddress1 {
            get {
                return this.remitterAddress1Field;
            }
            set {
                this.remitterAddress1Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string remitterAddress2 {
            get {
                return this.remitterAddress2Field;
            }
            set {
                this.remitterAddress2Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string remitterAddress3 {
            get {
                return this.remitterAddress3Field;
            }
            set {
                this.remitterAddress3Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string payerOtherInfo1 {
            get {
                return this.payerOtherInfo1Field;
            }
            set {
                this.payerOtherInfo1Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string payerOtherInfo2 {
            get {
                return this.payerOtherInfo2Field;
            }
            set {
                this.payerOtherInfo2Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string beneficiaryFirstName {
            get {
                return this.beneficiaryFirstNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.beneficiaryFirstNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string beneficiaryMiddleName {
            get {
                return this.beneficiaryMiddleNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.beneficiaryMiddleNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string beneficiaryLastName1 {
            get {
                return this.beneficiaryLastName1Field;
            }
            set {
                this.beneficiaryLastName1Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string beneficiaryLastName2 {
            get {
                return this.beneficiaryLastName2Field;
            }
            set {
                this.beneficiaryLastName2Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string beneficiaryNationality {
            get {
                return this.beneficiaryNationalityField;
            }
            set {
                this.beneficiaryNationalityField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string beneficiaryMobile {
            get {
                return this.beneficiaryMobileField;
            }
            set {
                this.beneficiaryMobileField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string beneficiaryEmailID {
            get {
                return this.beneficiaryEmailIDField;
            }
            set {
                this.beneficiaryEmailIDField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string beneficiaryAddress1 {
            get {
                return this.beneficiaryAddress1Field;
            }
            set {
                this.beneficiaryAddress1Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string beneficiaryAddress2 {
            get {
                return this.beneficiaryAddress2Field;
            }
            set {
                this.beneficiaryAddress2Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string beneficiaryAddress3 {
            get {
                return this.beneficiaryAddress3Field;
            }
            set {
                this.beneficiaryAddress3Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string beneficiaryBankBICCode {
            get {
                return this.beneficiaryBankBICCodeField;
            }
            set {
                this.beneficiaryBankBICCodeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string beneficiaryIBAN {
            get {
                return this.beneficiaryIBANField;
            }
            set {
                this.beneficiaryIBANField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string beneficiaryBranchName {
            get {
                return this.beneficiaryBranchNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.beneficiaryBranchNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string beneficiaryID {
            get {
                return this.beneficiaryIDField;
            }
            set {
                this.beneficiaryIDField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string benOtherInfo1 {
            get {
                return this.benOtherInfo1Field;
            }
            set {
                this.benOtherInfo1Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string benOtherInfo2 {
            get {
                return this.benOtherInfo2Field;
            }
            set {
                this.benOtherInfo2Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string transferPurpose {
            get {
                return this.transferPurposeField;
            }
            set {
                this.transferPurposeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string chargeType {
            get {
                return this.chargeTypeField;
            }
            set {
                this.chargeTypeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string optionalField1 {
            get {
                return this.optionalField1Field;
            }
            set {
                this.optionalField1Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string optionalField2 {
            get {
                return this.optionalField2Field;
            }
            set {
                this.optionalField2Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string optionalField3 {
            get {
                return this.optionalField3Field;
            }
            set {
                this.optionalField3Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string optionalField4 {
            get {
                return this.optionalField4Field;
            }
            set {
                this.optionalField4Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string optionalField5 {
            get {
                return this.optionalField5Field;
            }
            set {
                this.optionalField5Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string optionalField6 {
            get {
                return this.optionalField6Field;
            }
            set {
                this.optionalField6Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string optionalField7 {
            get {
                return this.optionalField7Field;
            }
            set {
                this.optionalField7Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string optionalField8 {
            get {
                return this.optionalField8Field;
            }
            set {
                this.optionalField8Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string optionalField9 {
            get {
                return this.optionalField9Field;
            }
            set {
                this.optionalField9Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string optionalField10 {
            get {
                return this.optionalField10Field;
            }
            set {
                this.optionalField10Field = value;
            }
        }
    }


    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // <auto-generated>
    //     This code was generated by a tool.
    //     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.6421
    //
    //     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
    //     the code is regenerated.
    // </auto-generated>
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //using System.Xml.Serialization;

    // 
    // This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=2.0.50727.3038.
    // 


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Envelope {

        private EnvelopeHeader[] headerField;

        private EnvelopeBody[] bodyField;


        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Header")]
        public EnvelopeHeader[] Header {
            get {
                return this.headerField;
            }
            set {
                this.headerField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Body")]
        public EnvelopeBody[] Body {
            get {
                return this.bodyField;
            }
            set {
                this.bodyField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public partial class EnvelopeHeader
    {
        // added manually
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://creation.soapws.progressoft.com/")]
        public string paymentOperation { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://creation.soapws.progressoft.com/")]
        public DateTime requestTimeStamp { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://creation.soapws.progressoft.com/")]
        public string securityToken { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://creation.soapws.progressoft.com/")]
        public string username { get; set; }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public partial class detail
    {
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public partial class EnvelopeBody
    {
        //added manually
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "createPayment", Namespace = "http://creation.soapws.progressoft.com/" )]
        public paymentItem item { get; set; }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Fault
    {

        private System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName faultcodeField;

        private string faultstringField;

        private string faultactorField;

        private detail detailField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName faultcode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.faultcodeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.faultcodeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string faultstring
        {
            get
            {
                return this.faultstringField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.faultstringField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType = "anyURI")]
        public string faultactor
        {
            get
            {
                return this.faultactorField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.faultactorField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public detail detail
        {
            get
            {
                return this.detailField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.detailField = value;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Brother, they have provided xsd file I need to pass the values using that file. If possible can you please provide step by step tutorial. Because I don't have any idea regarding this topic. Thanx In Advance.

Comment: I have added the xsd file for reference in Question.

Comment: Sorry brother but i am confused with the example you have provided. Because the xsd i provided is the one related to field i have to provide in the requestmessage field the one you have made is with the soap request

Comment: how you made the class for soap request

Comment: I went to the website in the namespace (see code) and got the template for the soap.  Then made the edits I documented with comments in the class.  Most namespaces have the schema that you can get with a webbrowser.